# Problems with NVIDIA 310.19 drivers on personal computer

Tags: nvidia

Any way to make Nvidia 310.19 driver to work on a desktop PC. I have i5 2500 processor, Leadtek GTX 460 OC video card, and so far these drivers messed up my whole Ubuntu 12.10 OS. Doesn't work no matter what I do. I tried to play for example Guild Wars 2 installed with PlayOnLinux and I have high fps losses. Need to know a way to fix this, to quit Windows 7 for ever.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after messing up with my system, i reinstalled ubuntu and i solved this way.
Right after installation, from the terminal:

```
sudo-apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade.
```

Restart your system and then install Synaptic:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

After that, open Synaptic and click on the bottom left "Personal filter" and on the top left you see "Missing Reccomended" (or viceversa). Click on that and then on the right install the linux version 3.5.0-18...click on that and choose "install", in the next windows  click on "YES" (these are the dependencies). When it's done, close synaptic, open the terminal and:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

Restart

I hope it helps. It did it for my GTS450 Nvidia video card.